# Android: Occasional StackOverflowError on SharedPreferences.Editor.Commit in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, sharedpreferences

I'm facing a weird issue where I am occasionally getting a `StackOverflowError` on calling `SharedPreferences.Editor.Commit()`. Problem occurs only sometimes and on Emulator only. If I rerun the app and call commit for the same value - everything is fine.

Seems rather random, and not something I ever saw on a physical device with the same code base. Seeing this on Pixel 3 API 29 Emulator image. Wondering if its an emulator issue.

Would like to know the cause for this error coming up randomly and what should be done about it?

**Exception stack trace:**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-19
    java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 1040KB
        at java.lang.String.getChars(String.java:787)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.append(FastXmlSerializer.java:115)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.append(FastXmlSerializer.java:139)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.escapeAndAppendString(FastXmlSerializer.java:163)
        at com.android.internal.util.FastXmlSerializer.text(FastXmlSerializer.java:413)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeValueXml(XmlUtils.java:662)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:307)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:276)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:242)
        at com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils.writeMapXml(XmlUtils.java:199)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.writeToFile(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:778)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$900(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:55)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$2.run(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:647)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.enqueueDiskWrite(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:666)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.access$100(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:55)
        at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl$EditorImpl.commit(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:585)
```

Comment: did you try `editor.apply()`

Comment: Issue is completely random, so I haven't tried editor.apply(). The only difference between commit() and apply() the latter is asynchronous, so I doubt it would make a difference.